# If $ |\phi_1| <| \phi_2| $ and $\phi = \phi_1 + \phi_2 $ then $\mathrm {Ind} _{\phi} (0) = \mathrm {Ind} _{\phi_2} (0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Let $ \phi1, \phi2: [0,1] \to \mathbb {C} $ be Paths, such that $ |\phi_1 (t) | <| \phi_2 (t) | $ for all $ t \in [0,1] $. If $ 0 \leq t \leq 1 $, we set $\phi (t) = \phi_1 (t) + \phi_2 (t)$. **Prove tha**t $ 0 \notin \phi_1^* \cup \phi_2^* $ and that $ \mathrm {Ind} _{\phi} (0) = \mathrm {Ind} _{\phi_2} (0)$.

We have $ 0 \notin \phi_1^* \cup \phi_2 ^ * $ because, if $ t \in [0, 1]$, it comes:
$$
0 \leq | \phi_1 (t) | <| \phi_2 (t) |\qquad ,\qquad 0 <| \phi_2 (t) | - | \phi_1 (t) |\leq | \phi_1 (t) +  \phi_2 (t) | = | \phi (t) |
$$

For $ 0 \leq t, u \leq 1 $, let us set:
$$
\gamma (u, t) := u \phi (t) + (1 - u) \phi_2 (t) 
$$
I want to show that $ \sigma $ realizes a homotopy, in $ \mathbb {C} ^ * $, but I can't show that $\phi$ and $\phi_2$ are paths with the same endpoints.
Did what I wrote solve this problem? Is there any other easy way to fix this problem?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344094/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly $\phi_{i}$ must be closed curves, and $\phi_{1}(t)\neq 0$.
Attach a bridge between $\phi_{1}(0)$ and $\phi_{2}(0)$ and modify $\phi_{1}$ to get a closed curve that shares the same starting point as $\phi_{2}$. More explicitly, let
$\varphi_{1}(t)=
\begin{cases}
(1-t)\phi_{2}(0)+t\phi_{1}(0), t\in [0,1] \\
\phi_{1}(t-1),t\in [1,2] \\
(3-t)\phi_{1}(0)+(t-2)\phi_{2}(0),t\in [2,3]
\end{cases}$

$\varphi_{2}(t)=
\begin{cases}
\phi_{2}(0),t\in [0,1]\\
\phi_{2}(t-1),t\in [1,2]\\
\phi_{2}(0),t\in [2,3]
\end{cases}$

Prove the proposition with $\phi_{i}$ replaced by $\varphi_{i}$.